# Keep service running in background even user clear memory

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-background, android-backup-service

I have a service as follows:

```
public class service extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Intent intents = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intents);
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

It worked well, and I can check the service is running when I go to Application setting. However, if I clear all applications by the long press the home button and clear them. I did not see my running service. How can I maintain my service running in the background, even the user clear the apps or memory? Thank all

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hellobootservice"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true"
                android:process=":hello"
                android:name=".service" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I have been into such situation but i couldn't figure how.. although some big apps like Instagram is managed to stay alive even with clearing the memory.. I wish someone could point that out.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
return START_NOT_STICKY;
```

with

```
return START_STICKY;
```

inside **onStartCommand()**.

Comment: for somehow this might not work I don't know.. I will wait the OP to confirm that ..

Comment: Thank Rahul Sharma. I tried it however it worked in another way. When I long press the home button and clear all running app (included my app.), the service will be call the onCreate function. It looks to make another service, instead of maintaining it. For example, if my service is used for reading Bluetooth message and initial connection in onCreate(), it means the initial connection of Bluetooth will call whenever I clear the app, instead of just listen data

Answer (score 0):

Use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) to call service periodically.

Init AlarmManager, you can call in **MainActivity**:

```
public void startAlert() {
    int i = 5;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            1000 * 5, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Create class extends **BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("Alarm...");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(!isMyServiceRunning(YourService.class,context)) {
        System.out.println("Alarm... services starting...");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("Alarm... services already running...");
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass,Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", true+"");
            return true;
        }
    }
    Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", false+"");
    return false;
}}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".services.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```

When I try in Android 8.1 alarm not repeat every 5 seconds, but run every 1 minutes.